# LDAP : one suffix : search multiple separate Active Directory

Tags: centos, ldap, openldap

I have configured an OpenLDAP 2.4.23 as a proxy to multiple separate Active Directory, it works fine when each AD as a different suffix/search base.

I have an use case to fullfil : one application server is only able to check ONE LDAP server and it allows only to check ONE search base, and the users are in several seperate Active Directory.

So I would like to configure OpenLDAP (or any other free directory) to work as a proxy and it should try each Active Directory to find is the user exists there, if not check the next Active Directory.

I have an unique key for each user (so no problem with duplicate).

I have already tried :

- to set multiple databases with the same suffix but openldap is not happy with that config
- to use meta (but the search base cannot be the same for two entries)

If you have any idea how to proceed I would be grateful.

Comment: Is there some in-depth up-to-date book on playing with relay and rewrites ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay found a solution :

an entry point of type meta

several subentries of type ldap with suffixmassaging.

Comment: I know this answer is 5 years old, but still: Could you be so kind and add some more information?. If you could add configuration examples would be great.

Comment: Another question: do you think this method could check first in the OpenLDAP and then, if doesn't exist any record, query a separate Active Directory?

Comment: Found an example here: https://web.archive.org/web/20130130094844/http://blog.sejo.be/2010/01/8/openldap-en-3-ad-servers/  and here https://github.com/kgalal/meta-ldap/blob/master/include/slapd-frontend.conf  (in fact the whole project: https://github.com/kgalal/meta-ldap/blob/)